# Chrome: Date sent in "yyyy-MM-dd" format getting changed to "yyyy-dd-MM" in chrome while sending API request in URL

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, datetime, browser

I'm getting calendar information by passing start & end dates (with **yyyy-MM-dd** explicitly) like this:

DATE TRANSFORM:

```
initDates = () => {
this.startDate = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, 1);
this.endDate = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 11, 31);
this.calendarStartDate = this.datePipe.transform(this.startDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
this.calendarEndDate = this.datePipe.transform(this.endDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd')};
```

SERVICE called with start & end dates:

```
this.getCalendarByCodeAndDates(url, calendarCode, this.calendarStartDate, this.calendarEndDate);

getCalendarByCodeAndDates = (url: string, calenderCode: string = '', startDate: string = '', endDate: string = '') => {
  return this.http.get(encodeURI(`${url}?calendarCode=${calenderCode}&startDate=${startDate}&endDate=${endDate}`))
  .pipe(map(response => response),
    catchError(err => throwError(err))
  )};
```

But in the network request of chrome, it gets converted to US time format **(yyy-dd-MM)**. I'm not sure why it's taking the default localization though explicitly i'm passing the format.

It works in some of the windows systems & not in others. Not able to get the behavior of it. This happens only in Chrome.

Any solution for that? (Attached screenshot of network request)

[image: Network request (start & end dates)]

Comment: Where's the bit where you're explicitly formatting the date?

Comment: I've updated the description with dates i'm passing.

Comment: Your network request screenshot shows it is formatted `YYYY-MM-DD`, "2021-01-01" to "2021-12-31". Your problem seems to be that the backend isn't returning any data for those date ranges.

Answer (score 1):

what's your type for 'startDate' ?
if it's Date, you need format it.

you can write debug code in your file, to show it's real value, like :
`alert(startDate)`

```js
function getYmd(date) {
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var strDate = date.getDate();
    if (month >= 1 && month <= 9) {
        month = "0" + month;
    }
    if (strDate >= 0 && strDate <= 9) {
        strDate = "0" + strDate;
    }
    var currentdate = year + '-' + month + '-' + strDate;
    return currentdate;
}
```

Comment: because you concat url with startDate, not calendarStartDate

Comment: No, it's function parameter. I've added the service in the description & updated.

Comment: you need customer Date.toString, don't depend chrome, code writed in reply content.

Comment: The start & end dates as string is got from Angular date pipe "this.datePipe.transform(this.endDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd')};" similar to the function you've written. It does that for you. The issue is while chrome sending the request.

Comment: did you add `alert(startDate)` before http request?

Comment: Yes, it was in string "yyyy-MM-dd".

Answer (score 0):

I got to know the issue, here it is:

```
const startDateString = new Date(startDate.getFullYear(), startDate.getMonth(), startDate.getDate()).toLocaleDateString();
const formattedStartDate = this.getHyphenSeparatedDate(startDateString);
```

Converting to localeString() was the issue, as chrome by default takes "en-us" as the locale & hence was appearing as "yyyy-d-M".
After removing it, and do the conversion as either:

1. Manually create a function to format at is in the above answer
2. Use Angular in-built date transform

Both worked. Also, needed to invalidate cache from AWS cloudfront.
But still not sure why chrome is doing that...